# How to compare 2 tables with dates and check which date is missing and insert the date using Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, compare

How to compare 2 tables with dates and check which date is missing and insert the date using Mysql ??

table 1 : appweb_ind_exeindicadores - COLUMN: dataindicador

table 2 : calendteste - COLUMN: dataindicador2

IMAGE:

[image: table 01]

IMAGE:

[image: table 02]

Comment: Use a `SELECT` query that gets all the rows from table 2 that aren't in table 1. Then use that as the source data for an `INSERT INTO table1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the below to get the list of dates in one table but not the other, and then write an INSERT around this to add it in.

```
-- This will give you the dates in table 1 but not in table 2
SELECT DISTINCT table1.date
FROM table1
WHERE table1.date NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT table2.date2 FROM table2)
```

Comment: in image 1 of table 1, I have some dates that are not appearing for example: 2021-09-11 and 2021-09-14, I need to enter these dates so that the query checks and insert manually

Answer (score 0):

If you want unique dates in `calendteste`, I would suggest that you let the *database* do the verification.  So, create a unique constraint on the column:

```
alter table calendteste add constraint unq_calendteste_dataindicador2
    unique (dataindicador2);
```

Then, you can insert the rows and use `on duplicate key update` to handle the duplicates:

```
INSERT INTO calendteste (dataindicador2)
    SELECT distinct dataindicador
    FROM appweb_ind_exeindicadores
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dataindicador2 = VALUES(dataindicador2);
```

The actual logic is a no-op -- no update happens but the duplicate key error is ignored.  This is the *safe* way to ensure that the column does not have duplicates.

Comment: in image 1 of table 1, I have some dates that are not appearing for example: 2021-09-11 and 2021-09-14, I need to enter these dates so that the query checks and insert manually